# Is there a context aware way of navigating a JSON file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: json, intellij-idea

The company I work at has placed all externalised strings in one huge JSON file and it's frankly horrific to attempt to find anything in it. There's a HUGE amount of duplicated keys that are only unique when taken in context of their parent nodes making it a lot of work to find the right key.

Is there any way (a plug-in maybe?) I could navigate this file in a context aware fashion? I'm hoping for something like the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> overview, but where I can enter something like `parent.child.property` to navigate to a specific property. I've tried searching for something like this, but it's frankly very difficult to find something this specific with all the matches JSON and IntelliJ bring up.

Comment: I'm also working on a project where the translation messages are in JSONs and this would be really useful. I haven't found any plugin for it though. Maybe we should create a feature request on youtrack.jetbrains.com to allow this style of a navigation in JSON files somehow. If you do, share the link to the issue in the comments so that I can vote for it : )

Comment: That's a good idea. I've written up a brief feature requests here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139480